# ACPI Error : No pointer back to namespace node in package 00000000

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bootloader

I am getting this error during boot (system boots successfully after that and works fine)

> ACPI Error : No pointer back to namespace node in package 00000000

why is it and is it a matter of concern?